# Free open-access peer-reviewed math journals

Tags: big-list, journals

Is there any free (as in free beer, i.e., no publication fees or other fees whatsoever), open-access (free and open access to everyone) and peer-reviewed mathematics journal?

I am interested in a list of journals. I am particularly interested in my field which is low dimensional topology and geometry and geometric group theory.

The observation how well a site like MathOverflow or Math Stack Exchange works makes me wonder if a similar system does exist for the peer-reviewing and publication process itself.

Comment: I believe The Electronic Journal of Combinatorics (http://www.combinatorics.org/) qualifies. But this is of course not a general journal.

Comment: @Sam Thanks for posting this comment. I found that journal and was delighted to see that the articles weren't much beyond my understanding. Do you know any more journals like this ?

Comment: _Theory and Applications of Categories_

Comment: Depends on how wide your definition of journal is: http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/pj.html

Comment: @PerAlexandersson is it consistently peer-reviewed?

Comment: @quid I just wondered about this question after seeing this article (http://www.sciencealert.com/this-woman-has-illegally-uploaded-millions-of-journal-articles-in-an-attempt-to-open-up-science). I am interested in a list of journals. Of course I am also particularly interested in my field which is low dimensional topology and geometry and geometric group theory.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; I added it to the main post.

Comment: I'm an undergrad looking to start reading papers. Please tell me some good journals.

Comment: "Algebraic Combinatorics" (https://alco.centre-mersenne.org/) is a "new" journal which is free open-access. See the introductory editorial here: https://alco.centre-mersenne.org/item/ALCO_2018__1_1_1_0/

Comment: In an ideal world this would be every journal

Answer (score 35):

You're asking for "diamond" open access (to contrast with the gold open access --- peer reviewed but not free --- and the green open access --- free but not peer reviewed). Here are some math journals of this type, that use arXiv as a repository (socalled "overlay journals"):

- [Discrete Analysis](https://submissions.scholasticahq.com/sites/discrete-analysis) ([blog](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2015/09/10/discrete-analysis-an-arxiv-overlay-journal/))
- [Symmetry, Integrability and Geometry](http://www.emis.de/journals/SIGMA/)
- [Logical Methods in Computer Science](http://www.lmcs-online.org/index.php)

A more complete list can be accessed at the [Directory of Open Access Journals (doaj.org)](https://doaj.org/search?source=%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22filtered%22%3A%7B%22filter%22%3A%7B%22bool%22%3A%7B%22must%22%3A%5B%7B%22term%22%3A%7B%22_type%22%3A%22journal%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22term%22%3A%7B%22index.classification.exact%22%3A%22Mathematics%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22term%22%3A%7B%22index.has_apc.exact%22%3A%22No%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22term%22%3A%7B%22bibjson.editorial_review.process.exact%22%3A%22Peer%20review%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22query_string%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%22mathematics%22%2C%22default_operator%22%3A%22AND%22%7D%7D%7D%7D%2C%22from%22%3A0%2C%22size%22%3A10%7D)

Comment: Well, there is some terminological conventions that vary. In some circle, Gold OA means that a journal opens its (typeset) articles, whtether or not they charge for publishing; and Green OA means that a journal allows the peer-reviewed, but not typeset "postprint" to be made available in a repository by the authors. Just to mention that most Green OA articles *are* peer-reviewed, just not typeset by the journal.

Comment: It's good to see that LMCS is now an arxiv overlay. If I remember rightly at some point in the past it wasn't.

Answer (score 30):

As other answers mention, such journals certainly exist. Two examples of general journals that fit this definition are

[Journal de l'École polytechnique — Mathématiques](https://jep.math.cnrs.fr/index.php/JEP/)

[Documenta Mathematica](https://www.elibm.org/series?q=se:2204)

Answer (score 28):

The *New York Journal of Mathematics* (http://nyjm.albany.edu/) is a peer reviewed and free online general math journal. It has been publishing since the mid-1990s. It is not an ArXiv overlay journal. Published articles appear on the journal website.

Answer (score 25):

[Acta Mathematica](http://www.mittag-leffler.se/publications/acta-mathematica), a top journal, is fully open access by special arrangement with the Institut Mittag-Leffler.

Answer (score 22):

**Yes**; only in my research area there are two: [ETNA](http://etna.math.kent.edu/) (Electronic Transactions on Numerical Analysis) and [ELA](http://repository.uwyo.edu/ela/) (Electronic Journal of Linear Algebra). They are both from noncommercial publishers, one funded by a university and one by a professional society.

Answer (score 21):

*Annales de l'Institut Fourier* are now an open access journal: http://aif.cedram.org

Some other journals in France (serious but less known):

*Confluentes Mathematici*: http://cml.cedram.org

*North-Western European Journal of Mathematics*: http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~nwejm/

One can also mention the *Electronic Journal of Differential Equations*
http://ejde.math.txstate.edu/ which exists since 1993

Answer (score 19):

There is a list of Diamond free open access journal here:

https://www.cimpa.info/en/node/62

We try to keep it updated.

Answer (score 18):

There are plenty of journals which charge no fees, and online access is free.
I am surprised that nobody mentioned the Bulletin of the AMS.

Some other examples are Conformal Geometry and Dynamics (electronic only):
 http://www.ams.org/journals/ecgd/2014-18-06/S1088-4173-2014-00265-3/

Journal of mathematical Physics, analysis and geometry (only electronic version is free), http://jmage.ilt.kharkov.ua/

All these are peer-reviewed and actually of high quality.

Comment: BAMS is  not a typical mathematics journal, in that it publishes no or hardly any original research, but mostly surveys/expositions and book reviews. The Notices of AMS are free too, but the same applies (though in a different way).

Answer (score 15):

The [Bulletin of the Iranian Mathematical Society](http://bims.iranjournals.ir/) is free access and peer-reviewed journal publishing in English.

Comment: (+1) And with reasonable time of review.

Comment: They seemed to have moved to Springer and introduced APC's now.

Answer (score 15):

A very recent (diamond open-access) journal has been lauched with the support of many major research institutions in France:

> [Annales Henri Lebesgue](https://annales.lebesgue.fr/index.php/AHL/)

Also, the editors and founders wrote a small paper ([French](https://annales.lebesgue.fr/contents/AHL2017-00fr.pdf), [English](https://annales.lebesgue.fr/contents/AHL2017-00en.pdf)) in order to emphasize the relevance of struggling for an open access world nowadays, and describing how the journal works.

Answer (score 13):

[INTEGERS: The Electronic Journal of Combinatorial Number Theory](http://www.integers-ejcnt.org/)

Published since its inception 15+ years ago as free and peer-reviewed electronic journal; by now it is in addition available in print (not freely, of course).

In addition to Combinatorial Number Theory, as the name indicates, it also has a focus on Game Theory.

Answer (score 11):

Journal of Integer Sequences:
https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/

Electronic Journal of Qualitative Theory of Differential Equations
http://www.math.u-szeged.hu/ejqtde/index.html

Answer (score 8):

Australasian Journal of Combinatorics: http://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au

Moved a couple of years ago from print/subscription to online/free, using the accumulated surplus from many years of small profits on subscriptions to fund the ongoing costs (which are not very high).

Answer (score 7):

There are two excellent (new) open access journals from Cambridge University Press:

Forum of Mathematics, Sigma: http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayJournal?jid=FMS

and

Forum of Mathematics, Pi: http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayJournal?jid=FMP

I think they both cover the spectrum of pure mathematics (though they don't say 'pure' in their descriptions)

Comment: So, the first is for papers about sums, and the second, for papers about products?

Comment: Seems to have APC = Article Processing Charge ...

Comment: they say, 
"for the first three years Cambridge University Press will waive the publication charges"
and it also says that only authors with access to funds will be expected to pay (indeed I published in the one on sums and did not have to pay)

Comment: As stated on their webpage (e.g. here http://journals.cambridge.org/action/newsTop?jid=FMS ) papers submitted after Jan.1 2016 will be charged APC after acceptance, if the authors have access to funds. But I cannot find anywhere on their website *how much* the APC is!

Comment: (-1) So it is NOT free open access. And typically it is a very bad system: paying for being published totally discredits the level of the articles.

Answer (score 7):

[International Journal of Group Theory](http://www.theoryofgroups.ir/) is a free peer-reviewed journal published by the University of Isfahan in English.

Answer (score 6):

The original question asked about low dimensional topology and geometry. For sufficiently algorithmic research in these areas, the [Journal of Computational Geometry](http://jocg.org/) may be relevant. For instance, a recent issue includes a paper on the [space complexity of recognizing low-dimensional manifolds](http://jocg.org/index.php/jocg/article/view/212).

Another algorithmic journal that I regularly publish in, free-as-in-beer to both authors and readers, is the [Journal of Graph Algorithms and Applications](http://jgaa.info/).

Answer (score 5):

Two more FAPP (for all practical purposes). Nobody mentioned them.

With slighty more applied emphasis http://www.complex-systems.com/contribute.html

All issues besides the current one (four per year) are open access and there are no fees.

Also, don't forget PNAS. http://www.pnas.org/site/authors/guidelines.xhtml Open access after one year. Very fast reviewing. PNAS has always published top quality short mathematical papers. http://www.pnas.org/content/by/section/Mathematics?FIRSTINDEX=10

Comment: It has occasionally published some less than top quality papers (at least one of which was not properly copy-edited, in my opinion)

Comment: "Open access: Authors of research articles may pay a surcharge of $1,350 to make their paper freely available through PNAS open access option."

Comment: That's for immediate open access. PNAS becomes open without payment after about a year.

Comment: So it is not free open access...

Answer (score 5):

[Annales Academiæ Scientiarum Fennicæ](http://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/) is a very good, free and open access journal. It primarily publishes papers in analysis but is open to all fields of mathematics. Geometric group theory fits pretty well into the profile of the journal. The MathSciNet Mathematical Citation Quotient for 2016 was 0.75.

Answer (score 5):

[Annales Mathematicae Silesianae](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/amsil)

*Annales Mathematicae Silesianae publishes significant research and survey papers from all branches of pure and applied mathematics, and reports of meetings. It welcomes contributed papers that develop important, new mathematical ideas and results or solve outstanding problems.
The journal does not have article processing charges (APCs) nor article submission charges*

Answer (score 4):

The [Far Eastern Mathematical Journal](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/journal.phtml?jrnid=dvmg&wshow=details&option_lang=eng) is free access and peer-reviewed journal publishing in Russian and English.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.compositionality-journal.org/

> Compositionality describes and quantifies how complex things can be assembled out of simpler parts. Compositionality, the journal, is an open-access journal for research using compositional ideas, most notably of a category-theoretic origin, in any discipline. Topics may concern foundational structures, an organizing principle, or a powerful tool. Example areas include but are not limited to: computation, logic, physics, chemistry, engineering, linguistics, and cognition.

Answer (score 4):

[Combinatorial Theory](https://escholarship.org/uc/combinatorial_theory) is a new open-access journal in combinatorics that replaces Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A, whose entire editorial board recently resigned to from it (effective January 2021).

[Algebraic Combinatorics](https://alco.centre-mersenne.org/) is the result of a similar effort, and is the successor of Journal of Algebraic Combinatorics, a Springer journal that continues in diminished form.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from *[Theory and Applications of Categories](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/)*, which I mentioned in the comments, there is a new journal that publishes higher category theory and related areas, namely *[Higher Structures](https://journals.mq.edu.au/index.php/higher_structures)*.

> This journal publishes articles that make significant new contributions to mathematical science using higher structures, or that significantly advance our understanding of the foundational aspects of the theory of such structures. The scope of the journal includes: higher categories, operads and their generalisations, and applications of these to Algebra, Geometry, Topology, Combinatorics, Logic and Mathematical Physics.

One very good point is that the journal [uses an explicit open access license](https://journals.mq.edu.au/index.php/higher_structures/about/editorialPolicies#openAccessPolicy), rather than merely being free (as in your favourite bubbly drink) to read.

Answer (score 3):

1. [Cahier de topologie et géométrie différentielle catégoriques](http://cahierstgdc.com/)
2. [Theory and Applications of Categories](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/)
3. [Categories and General Algebraic Structures with Applications](http://www.cgasa.ir/)
4. [New York Journal of Mathematics](http://nyjm.albany.edu/nyjm.html)

Comment: +1 New York J. of Math. ... I have published there.

Answer (score 3):

Last year I compiled a list of such journals related that are either generic or related to algebraic geometry: http://math.commelin.net/agdoaj.html.
For a long list of journals see https://thomas1111.wordpress.com/2013/06/29/some-serious-open-acess-journals/ by Thomas Sauvaget.

Answer (score 3):

[Advances in Combinatorics](https://advances-in-combinatorics.scholasticahq.com/) is a new arXiv overlay journal that ''aims to be a top-level specialist journal in combinatorics.'' The journal has a very strong [editorial board](https://advances-in-combinatorics.scholasticahq.com/editorial-board) with Dan Král' and Tim Gowers serving as managing editors.  See this [post](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2018/06/04/a-new-journal-in-combinatorics/) and this [post](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2019/10/30/advances-in-combinatorics-fully-launched/) on Tim Gowers's blog for more information.  As of now, the journal is completely free beer, with financial and administrative support from Queen's University Library.

Answer (score 3):

The [Bulletin of the Irish Mathematical Society](http://www.irishmathsoc.org/bulletin/)

Answer (score 2):

[The Journal of Singularities](http://www.journalofsing.org/index.html). The editorial board is impressive, and it seems to be pretty much an ideal case of open access journals: *"... In order to fund the Center, and to expand our activities in the future, we rely on video-textbook sales (at low prices), licensing deals with institutions and publishers, donations, investors, and advertising revenue. Our goal is to grow to the point where we can fund additional activities, such as: in-office tutorials and review sessions for undergraduates in the Greater Boston area, 24/7 video-chat tutoring, postdoctoral research positions (including office space), hosting of mathematics research conferences, and adding more Worldwide journals."*

Comment: Don't vote this journal down unless you check it. The description provided above is weird, but the journal seems reasonable. It seems really free and it is referees in MathSciNet.

Answer (score 2):

[Journal of Logic and Analysis](http://logicandanalysis.org/index.php/jla/index)

"This journal examines the interaction between ideas or techniques from mathematical logic and other areas of mathematics, especially, but not limited to, pure and applied analysis. "

Answer (score 2):

The [Hardy Ramanujan Journal](https://hrj.episciences.org/) publishes papers in number theory. It is totally open access, peer reviewed and is an epijournal based on the HAL platform.

Answer (score 1):

The [Journal of Nonsmooth Analysis and Optimization](https://jnsao.episciences.org) is a "fair" (in particular diamond) open access journal that launched this year on the episciences arXiv overlay platform.

Other journals on that platform that I haven't seen mentioned yet are the [journal of Groups, Complexity, Cryptology](https://gcc.episciences.org) and the [Epijournal de Géométrie Algébrique](https://epiga.episciences.org).

<sub>*(Disclaimer: I am one of the Managing Editors of JNSAO.)*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The American Mathematical Society has a new diamond open access journal called the [Communications of the American Mathematical Society](https://www.ams.org/publications/journals/journalsframework/aboutcams).

Answer (score 1):

[Annals of representation theory](https://art.centre-mersenne.org/), a diamond open access electronic journal. From the description on the webpage

> The Annals of Representation Theory is a diamond open access electronic international research journal. It is dedicated to publishing top quality original research articles in the general area of contemporary representation theory, including its algebraic, geometric and combinatorial aspects.

> There is no fee for authors, and there is immediate open access to published papers.

> The journal is owned and published by NTNU. The web-publisher is Centre Mersenne. The journal is run by and for mathematicians.

See https://art.centre-mersenne.org/page/editorial-team_en/ for the list of editors.